# Detect UITextField autosuggestion text replacement

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

The problem I have is that I want to detect when the UITextField's text is being changed when the user taps on autosuggestion word.
Using textFieldShouldChangeTextinRange will also react to pasting any text from clipboard, but I want to process EXACTLY the autosuggested text replacement.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, there is no UITextfield's delegates to implement it.